# Java: How to wait 1 second in a GUI

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to make a Karaoke machine in Java, but I do not know how to delay the program in a GUI. I have searched through loads of topics on this site but I have still not found a solution that works for this.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class KaraokeMachine extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    ClassLoader Idr = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    JLabel lbl1 = new JLabel( "" );
    JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel( "" );
    JLabel lbl3 = new JLabel( "" );
    JLabel lbl4 = new JLabel( "" );
    JButton btn = new JButton( "Play" );
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int z = 0;
    JPanel pnl = new JPanel();

    public KaraokeMachine()
    {
        super( "Karaoke" );
        setSize( 520, 280 );
        setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        pnl.add( lbl1 );
        pnl.add( lbl2 );
        pnl.add( lbl3 );
        pnl.add( lbl4 );
        pnl.add( btn );
        btn.addActionListener( this );
        add( pnl ); setVisible( true );
    }

    public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent event )
    {
        if( event.getSource() == btn )
        {
            //
        }
    }
    public static void main( String[] args ) throws InterruptedException
    {
        KaraokeMachine karaoke = new KaraokeMachine();
    }
}
```

I want to make the label change text after 1 second. I have tried `Thread.sleep` both in a catch statement and without where the `//` is, but without one, the compiler says that it is an error and with one, the program just delays for a few seconds and shows the result at the end, but none of the results in the middle. Can someone please tell me how I can make `lbl1` say "Everything", then one second later "Everything is" and then another second after that "Everything is Awesome!"? Thanks.

Comment: Learn about Java Threads. You can  use a single thread for this and there you could sleep()  or wait() for this to be happen.

Comment: Where is the code fragment that outputs the text **Everything is Awesome**??

Comment: Could you please provide a link that will tell me?

Comment: I left that out because I have tried many different codes that say "Everything is Awesome" and none of them work. Could someone please tell me one that does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't call the `sleep()` method inside your gui thread, otherwise all your interface will freeze. You should use a separate thread instead and communicate with your gui thread to tell him when to update the interface.

The best way to work with threads in a Swing application is using the `SwingWorker` object. In particular, it offer two hook methods that are `process` and `done` that are called directly in your gui thread and are a powerful way to publish progress done by your worker thread. In your case, you should do something like that:

```
SwingWorker<Void, String> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, String>(){

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
            this.publish("Everything");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            this.publish("Everything is");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            this.publish("Everything is Awesome!");
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<String> res){
            for(String text : res){
                 label.setText(text); 
            }
        }

    };

    worker.execute();
```

**P.S.:** you can call the `execute()` method only once on a worker object. If you want to call it multiple times you have to instantiate new objects.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very confused. Where do I put the SwingWorker?

Comment: The instantiation of the worker object can be done everywhere before you call worker.execute();  and the execute() method should be called where do you want to start executing the task.

Comment: But where in the code do I put that?

Comment: You could put it in place of `//` if you want to call it when the button is pressed.

Comment: Now I'm getting compiler messages saying that "public static void main ( String[] args )" is an illegal start of expression. How do I solve that?

Comment: This is a little off topic I think. Check that all brackets are present and if you still have the problem open another question.

Comment: Don't worry. I've fixed that. The only problem now is that can't find the symbol List<String> res.

Comment: Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: You have to add `import java.util.List;`

Comment: I've done that, but now it wants a return statement (sorry to keep asking, I'm quite new to java)

Comment: @DalekCaan99 if you have solved, can you accept the answer?

Comment: It's nearly solved. I'm just not sure what to do about this return statement.

Comment: yeah, I just update the snippet of code: you have to add `return null;` because `Void` (different from the void keyword) is an object.

Comment: IT WORKS! THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a `javax.swing.Timer`. It should be enough to replace the `//` in your code by:

```
        final AtomicInteger frame = new AtomicInteger(0);
        final String[] text = {
                "Everything",
                "Everything is",
                "Everything is Awesome!"
        };
        final Timer timer = new Timer(1000, null);
        timer.addActionListener((e) -> {
            lbl1.setText(text[frame.getAndIncrement()]);
            if (frame.get() >= text.length) {
                timer.stop();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
```